# Set Browser Cookies From Curl CookieJar/FIle

Tags: php, arrays, curl, httpcookie, cookiejar

I am setting/storing CURL cookies with :

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
```

And retrieving them / trying to set them in my browser with:

```
 setcookie($cookie);
```

But what goes inbetween please?

Cookie variable defining looks like:

```
`$cookie="cookie.txt"`;
```

Is there some way to parse the cookie file as an array?

Comment: Why did somebody mark it down? its not like there is really a proper solution on this site. Using this site is really demoralizing.

Comment: I'd really love an answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any official library that can do it for you.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410109/php-reading-a-cookie-file) has script to parse cookie file. Pay attention to answer about **HttpOnly**.

Or you might want to parse cookies directly from curl response. Then check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable).

Answer (score 0):

this is the way i done it

```
$cookies = [];
$lines = file($cookiesFile);
foreach($lines as $line) {
            if($line[0] !== '#' && $line[0] !== "\n") {
                $tokens = explode("\t", $line);
                $cookies[$tokens[5]] = trim($tokens[6]);
            }
        }
```